# Retrieving image data/ unstructured data from database and streaming it to the web browser for download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, filestream

I am developing a web app using ASP.NET MVC 4 that retrieve image data / unstructured data (scanned documents) from a SQL Server 2008 database to be downloaded via the web browser. It is not for viewing on the web browser, but it should be downloaded and viewed by the default program on the clients machine. My major problem is that the data is unrecognized by the PC after it has been downloaded. Need help to fix this problem.

Here is a snippet of the code.

Model

```
   public bool getData(string code)
   {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spReadDocumentCode", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        bool state = false;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =
          Convert.ToString(code);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                image = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
                // I pass the data to a public MemoryStream variable.
                ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"]); 
                state = true;
            }


            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();

            return state;
        }
        catch
        {

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();

            return false;
        }
```

Controller

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=3600, VaryByParam="code", NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult Document(string code)
    {

        MemoryStream img = null;
        if (Doc.getData(code))
        {
            img = Doc.getMemoryStream();

        }
        try
        {

            if (img == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            // I send back an image file, however I want to upgrade the code 
            // to send back any type of scanned documents stored on the database.
            return new FileStreamResult(img, "image/png");  
        }
        catch 
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: It seems like that data might be corrupt. Can you check that the amount of bytes stored in the database match the same amount of bytes in the downloaded file? If so, are you certain that the contents stored in the database are indeed correct and not truncated? I assume the data-type is VARBINARY(MAX).

Comment: StackOverflow is not a crowd-sourced debugging service.

Comment: @PabloRomeo Problem solved! It was being truncated.

Comment: Excellent, I'll post the comment as answer so that you can accept it then ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like that data might be corrupt.

Can you check that the amount of bytes stored in the database match the same amount of bytes in the downloaded file? If so, are you certain that the contents stored in the database are indeed correct and not truncated?

I assume the data-type is `VARBINARY(MAX)`